# Cast not valid but it used to be

Tags: c#, casting, datareader

I'm not sure what happened. This code was working fine yesterday but today when I try to run it I receive a "specified cast is not valid" error at the marked location. The query returns integers between 1 & 25. Inside the Access database, the field is of a data type 'number' with field size = 'long integer'.

Any clues on how to correct this?

```
 static void PopulateClientList()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Populating Client List...");
        Console.WriteLine("\r");
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConnABS);
        string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Client FROM ORDERS WHERE Status = 'On Hold';"; 
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
        //OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {

            //if (reader.HasRows)
            //{
              //  while (reader.Read())
               // {
                    //clientlist.Add(reader.GetInt32(0)); //cast not valid error happens here
                //}
           // }

             adapter.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() != "")
                    clientlist.Add((int)dt.Rows[i][0]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What did you change in the code? What did you change in the DB?

Comment: what is the value of reader[0] when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0)) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is likely that a value that exceeds the maximum of `Int32` has probably been added to your table.  Prior to this, your code would not throw an exception.

> the field is of a data type 'number' with field size = 'long integer'.

Then why are you reading it as an `Int32` here?:

```
clientlist.Add(reader.GetInt32(0)); //cast not valid error happens here
```

Change it to:

```
clientlist.Add(reader.GetInt64(0));
```

Depending on what `clientlist` is, you'll have to change its type to accept `Int64`s as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Inside the Access database, the field is of a data type 'number' with
>   field size = 'long integer'.

You're not using a long:

```
clientlist.Add(reader.GetInt32(0)); //cast not valid error happens here -> Use GetInt64
```

I suppose someone changed the DB field from int > long?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed the problem. Not sure how it happened though. Inside the database when I run the query the first row is blank. When the reader reads that and tries to add it to the list it wont do it because it is a null value.